# Creating an array of objects in JavaScript from Java

Tags: javascript, arrays, jsp, el

I'm trying to create an array of objects using:

```
var tax_data = new Array();
for (var i =0; i < ${Dates.size()}; i++) {
    tax_data.push({
        "period": "${Dates[i]}", 
        "Poids": ${WeightMesures[Dates[i]]}, 
        "Nombre de pas": ${WalkingMesures[Dates[i]]}, 
        "Pulsation": ${BpMesures[Dates[i]]} 
    });
}
```

but this doesn't work.

Is there an other method to put elements in this array ?

Comment: What is `${}` in your object?

Comment: expression language because im using it a jsp page

Comment: in your for loop, your never changing number so it'll run forever

Comment: Use `i` instead of `number` in `for` statement and remove `i++` from end of it.

Comment: You are incrementing `i` twice

Comment: i made all all modifications but it still don't work

Comment: Check that `${Dates.size()}` has content.

Comment: i've tested it and it does have content

Comment: Do you have any error in console?

Comment: The `${}` are evaluated on the **server**, but `i` only exists on the client. You cannot mix those (`${Dates[i]}`).

Comment: Also, this has nothing to do with JSON.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be mixing up iterating in JavaScript and iterating in your template engine. From `${Dates[i]}` it looks like you want `i` to be a variable in your template, but you've declared it as a variable in your generated JavaScript.

Something like (untested)

```
var tax_data = new Array();
<c:forEach begin="1" end="Dates.size()" var="i">
tax_data.push({"period": "${Dates[i]}", "Poids": ${WeightMesures[Dates[i]]}, "Nombre de pas": ${WalkingMesures[Dates[i]]}, "Pulsation": ${BpMesures[Dates[i]]} }) ;
</c:forEach>
```

should result in a row for each date in the JavaScript

```
var tax_data = new Array();
tax_data.push({"period": "2014-01-01", "Poids": 32, ... }) ;
tax_data.push({"period": "2014-02-01", "Poids": 32, ... }) ;
tax_data.push({"period": "2014-02-01", "Poids": 32, ... }) ;
```

There isn't a simple way of having the generated JavaScript reference then Dates table without writing out each row of it, either directly or in response to a separate ajax request.

Comment: no that's what i want
i want to get the i element ofDates table

Answer (score 0):

Pass the data to JavaScript variables first, then run your loop using the local vars:

```
var taxData = [],
index = 0,
dates = ${Dates},
weightMesures = ${WeightMesures},
walkingMesures = ${WalkingMesures},
bpMesures = ${BpMesures},
length = dates.length();

for (index; index < length}; index += 1) {
    taxData.push({
        "period": dates[i],
        "Poids": weightMesures[dates[i]],
        "Nombre de pas": walkingMesures[dates[i]],
        "Pulsation": bpMesures[dates[i]]
    });
}
```

Comment: @Mehdi: *"it doesn't work"* doesn't contain any information to would enable us to help you. Please be more specific.

Comment: what exactly is `${obj}` from anyways?  Java? ES6?

Comment: Have a look at the comments on the question.

Comment: i use tax_data array for morris.js chart and i dont get any chart when i run this

Comment: Server-side only?  Hell, the whole loop should be run server-side and return the compiled array to the JS code then

Comment: im using this in a jsp page for a JEE app and the ${} is EL i've tested it outside the loop and it does work

Comment: try changing taxData to tax_data the code I supplied

Comment: it gives the same result

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Pete.
I advice you to create in vanilla a Json Array And writing again vanilla to retrieve properties in a loop.
Thus you would check that works in JavaScript.
It's bad pattern to mix JSP (or other templating language) with client-side JavaScript. You'd rather let a servlet to push Json Array towards a client page and then parse Json with pure JavaScript

Answer (score -1):

Try this assuming you want to loop through Dates.size

```
var tax_data = [];
    for (var i =0 ;i< ${Dates.size()}; i++) {

        tax_data.push({"period": "${Dates[i]}", "Poids": ${WeightMesures[Dates[i]]}, "Nombre de pas": ${WalkingMesures[Dates[i]]}, "Pulsation": ${BpMesures[Dates[i]]} }) ;

        }
```

Comment: What's the difference?

Comment: I see... that alone won't help though (likely just a typo here). There are much bigger issues with that code.